# Can I place books as a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I created a church and made a solid golden altar. I typed up The Book of Matthew in a book and quill and then signed it. Can I place this on the alter so it can be read? Can I even place a book at all? Is there a mod that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Maybe with Mystcraft, but the standard vanilla way is just to leave it in a chest.

Comment: for looks use an enchantment table, for readability use item frame.  for mods, use bibliocraft

Comment: You could use an enchant table as the "for show" book, and then an item frame/chest with the actual book somewhere else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no vanilla way to place books in the world (except in a chest as MBraedley says).

[Bibliocraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1680480-16215xforgesmp-bibliocraft-v141-bookcases-armor-stands-shelves-printing-presses-lamps-tables-and-more-updated-09042013/) however has various ways of storing books in the world, the best looking way for a single book would probably be something like the desk:

[image: Desks in a row]

The desk will keep one book open (it can store up to 9 at a time in the latest version of Bibiliocraft) and right clicking on that book (if it is a book and quill or a written book) will allow you to read from the book directly. It will also store the page you were reading from when you exit the book.

Comment: Bibliocraft is *wonderful*. It is one of the most well-crafted mods out there. It's worth saying that the desk lets you read the book without picking it up.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wasn't sure you could read it while it was in the table, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can place an item frame, then place the book inside it. This will allow players to come up and see the book in the frame, then click it to take it into their inventory and read it.

Note that as of the latest snapshots, clicking an item frame once will give the item, and clicking an empty item frame will remove it from the wall. This lets you keep the item frame in place when the book is removed.

Comment: When I put the book in the frame, it only puts a picture of the book and the book remains in my inventory.  If I otherwise dispose of the book (e.g. put it in a chest) when I try to take the book from the frame it just disappears and does not go into my inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question but here is how I would do it in vanilla minecraft. Make an enchantment table and place it somewhere where the altar would be, then make a chest nearby and place the book in it. Although this wouldn't let you read the book from the enchantment table but it will seem as though the book is there since the texture is practically the same. The enchantment table will also add a little cool thing where whenever you go near it the book will open and flip through. So if you think of it, it would look as though you are reading the book from the table but in reality it is in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you place a book and quill on a lectern (which looks like a pulpit if you ask me).

Comment: Welcome on Arqade SE. You could (and should) improve your answer by using screenshots and/or add links to these elements (like a link to the wiki page or something like that).

Answer (score -1):

there is no legit way in minecraft vanilla (as of 1.6.2) to read a book without holding it

although as said above you can get a mod for that (best place to get forge mods is http://www.skydaz.com/)

Comment: Skydaz is sketchy at best. They don't appear to ask for permission to repackage modders' hard work.

Answer (score -1):

You can WITHOUT mods or hacks place the book in an item frame or a chest or one of the different kinds of chests.

Comment: This does not add anything to already existing answers.  Please don't duplicate information in existing answers.